# How can you refactor and make react less bulky and more readable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there any way to make React code such as the component I've posted below less clunky and more readable? Should I break out my table data into components somehow? Just wondering, as I'm new to this, and think that this doesn't look great, but I'm not sure. Thanks so much for any input.

```
class Profile extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        const { id } = this.props.match.params;
        this.props.getStarshipsData(id);
    }

    successfulLoad(itemStatus) {
        return (itemStatus === 'SUCCESS');
    }

    findPersonById(people, idNumber) {
        return people.filter(person => {
            return person.url === `http://swapi.co/api/people/${idNumber}/`;
        });
    }

    renderLoadingMessage() {
        if (!this.successfulLoad(this.props.starships.status)) {
            return <p id="loading-text">{ 'Loading' }</p>;
        }
        return null;
    }

    renderTable() {
        if (this.successfulLoad(this.props.starships.status)) {
            return (
                <table id="starship-data-table">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th className="starship-data-header">Name</th>
                            <th className="starship-data-header">Model</th>
                            <th className="starship-data-header">Length</th>
                            <th className="starship-data-header">Cost in Credits</th>
                            <th className="starship-data-header">Crew</th>
                            <th className="starship-data-header">Hyperdrive Rating</th>
                        </tr>
                        { this.renderStarships() }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            );
        }
        return null;
    }

    renderStarships() {
        if (this.successfulLoad(this.props.starships.status)) {
            const { starships } = this.props.starships.data;
                return (
                    starships.map((starship, index) => {
                        return (
                            <tr key={index} className="starship-container">
                                <td className="starship-data">{starship.name}</td>
                                <td className="starship-data">{starship.model}</td>
                                <td className="starship-data">{starship.length}</td>
                                <td className="starship-data">{starship.cost_in_credits}</td>
                                <td className="starship-data">{starship.crew}</td>
                                <td className="starship-data">{starship.hyperdrive_rating}</td>
                            </tr>
                        );
                    })
                );
        }
        return;
    }

    render() {
        const { id } = this.props.match.params;
        const { people } = this.props.people.data;
        const person = this.findPersonById(people, id)[0];

        return (
            <div id="profile-page">
                <div id="profile-attributes-container">
                    <div id="profile-picture-name">
                        <p className="profile-attribute">{ person.name } </p>
                        <img id="profile-picture" role="presentation" src={profilePicture} />
                    </div>
                    <div id="profile-row-1">
                        <p className="profile-attribute"> Hgt: { person.height } </p>
                        <p className="profile-attribute"> Mass: { person.mass } </p>
                        <p className="profile-attribute"> Hair: { person.hair_color } </p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="profile-row-2">
                        <p className="profile-attribute"> Eyes: { person.eye_color } </p>
                        <p className="profile-attribute"> Born: { person.birth_year } </p>
                        <p className="profile-attribute"> Gen: { person.gender } </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="starships-info">
                    <img id="starships-title" role="presentation" src={spaceship} />
                    <div id="starships-table">
                    { this.renderTable() }
                    { this.renderLoadingMessage() }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    const { starships, people } = state;
    return { starships, people };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        getStarshipsData: starships => {
            dispatch(starshipsActions.getStarshipsData(starships));
        },
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Profile);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use stateless functional components. These are normal functions that React will render as components. This is great for making code smaller and more readable!

The props are passed in as an object, so you can use object destructuring to access specific properties:

```
// returns a loading message
const LoadingMessage = ({message}) =>
  <p id="loading-text">{ message }</p>


// returns a <tbody> containing a row for each starship
const StarshipTableRows = ({starships}) =>
  <tbody>
    starships.map((starship, index) => 
      <tr key={index} className="starship-container">
        ['name', 'model', 'length', 'cost_in_credits', 'crew', 'hyperdrive_rating']
          .map(key => <td className="starship-data">{starship[key]}</td>)
      </tr>);
  </tbody>


// returns a <thead> containing headers for the table
const StarshipTableHeaders = () =>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      ['Name', 'Model', 'Length', 'Cost in Credits', 'Crew', 'Hyperdrive Rating']
        .map(key => <th className="starship-data-header">{key}</td>)
    </tr>
  </thead>


// returns a <table> containing starships
const StarshipTable = ({starships}) =>
  <table id="starship-data-table">
   <StarshipTableHeaders />
   <StarshipTableRows starships={starships.data} />
  </table>


// returns a profile page
const ProfilePage = ({person, profilePicture, spaceship, starships, successfulLoad}) => 
  <div id="profile-page">
    <div id="profile-attributes-container">
      <div id="profile-picture-name">
        <p className="profile-attribute">{ person.name } </p>
        <img id="profile-picture" role="presentation" src={profilePicture} />
      </div>
      <div id="profile-row-1">
        <p className="profile-attribute"> Hgt: { person.height } </p>
        <p className="profile-attribute"> Mass: { person.mass } </p>
        <p className="profile-attribute"> Hair: { person.hair_color } </p>
      </div>
      <div id="profile-row-2">
        <p className="profile-attribute"> Eyes: { person.eye_color } </p>
        <p className="profile-attribute"> Born: { person.birth_year } </p>
        <p className="profile-attribute"> Gen: { person.gender } </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="starships-info">
      <img id="starships-title" role="presentation" src={spaceship} />
      <div id="starships-table">
        { 
          successfulLoad
          ? <StarshipTable starships={starships} />
          : <LoadingMessage message="loading" />
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const { starships, people } = state;
  return { starships, people };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
      getStarshipsData: starships => {
          dispatch(starshipsActions.getStarshipsData(starships));
      },
  };
};

class Profile extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    this.props.getStarshipsData(id);
  }

  findPersonById(people, idNumber) {
    return people.filter(person => 
      person.url === `http://swapi.co/api/people/${idNumber}/`;
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    const { people } = this.props.people.data;
    const person = this.findPersonById(people, id)[0];
    const starships = this.props.starships;
    const successfulLoad = starships.status === 'SUCCESS';

    return <ProfilePage 
      person={person} 
      successfulLoad={successfulLoad} 
      starships={starships} 
      spaceship={null} 
      profilePicture={null}/>;
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Profile);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was missing, thanks so much, this will clean it up a lot!

Comment: Would you then break the stateless components out into their own files? (ie. loading message, StarshipTableRows, etc, all have their own files?) Also, I noticed that you don't have brackets in the arrow functions of your component declarations, I've never seen this, could you explain how that works? Thanks again, this answer was extremely helpful!

Comment: Yes, you can definitely put the Profile rendering functions in another file. Related components can be put in the same file - for example, StarshipTable/(Header/Rows) would be together, but you would only have to export StarshipTable. 

Because JSX gets compiled down to regular React.createElement calls, you can omit using brackets in the arrow functions (since we are evaluating a single expression instead of multiple statements).

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I'm having issues after changing this with starships being undefined in my starshipTableRows function. Perhaps due to the asynchronous call that's getting starships - any idea why this would be different now compared to what I had before? Thanks!

Comment: Ah, it looks like `starships` is a property of `starships.data`. So, instead of `<StarshipTableRows starships={starships.data} />` you would instead use `<StarshipTableRows starships={starships.data.starships} />` (or, you could change it in the `StarshipTableRows` function instead).

Comment: Ahhhh of course, this data structure is a bit confusing like that, in that the data is nested inside the state of the same name. Thanks again so much the help and explanations, I learned a lot from this question!